# DocuSign oAuth 2.0 for system to system integration

Tags: docusignapi

We are currently using basic authentication for our DocuSign apps. Our application requires no human interaction for envelope creation. Backend code does a basic authentication and creates the envelopes.
We want to move to oAuth 2.0. I went through DocuSign's web site and read about different kind of OAuth grant flows.
I downloaded there quickstart code (Authentication grant code flow) but it did not work for me as I was always getting HTTP error 404 at the time of redirection.  It seems, for our system integration JWT grant flow should work, but again it has a consent form, which requires someone to approve.

Can someone help me with sample code on oAuth 2.0 with System integration?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [administrative consent](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/consent/obtaining-admin-consent-internal/) for JWT which means that the organization need only consent once and the app can then be used by all users. No one will need to log in to DocuSign to use your integration.
I would like to help with the issues you had with quickstart, but not sure what language you tried.

Comment: I am not able to see exact same  options on DocuSign's admin screen, as the documentation shows. As far as QuickStart is concerned, I am getting an error after authorization code comes . I get HTTP 404 response code for URL http://localhost:8080/login&type=acg?code=<Code>. I get following message on screen. Oops, we have encountered a problem.

Message:

Dump:

Please check your account configuration. If you are unable to resolve the problem, open a new issue on GitHub.

Continue

Comment: The Admin console is because you need to set an organization. https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-create-org

Comment: as for the quickstart, what lang is this?

Comment: For QuickStart I am using Java

Comment: Can you restart and try again? if this happens all the time, would you mind doing a screen recording and send us? you can use https://icecreamapps.com/Screen-Recorder/ to record your screen and share the video

Comment: I got JWT grant flow working. I have a couple of questions related to private key. Is there any expiration on the private key ? Do I need to have one private key per application ?

Comment: no expiration. One per application is a good practice, but in theory you can use the same one for multiple apps.

Comment: Please mark question as resolved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Download a fresh Java Quickstart from https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/

Run Java Quickstart  in command line per these instructions: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/overview/#configuration > Java tab > Building and running Quickstart

Get JWT consent for app: Login > Dropdown: JSON Web Token Grant > Authenticate with DocuSign > Log In > Allow Access

Extract ds-java-auth-final.zip located at https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-java/blob/master/docs/ds-java-auth-final.zip

Fill in ds-java-auth-final/src/main/java/test.newOAuth/Config.java with your client-id and impersonated-user-guid from your Quickstart_folder/src/main/resources/application.json

Fill in your API account ID from the Apps and Keys page https://admindemo.docusign.com/authenticate?goTo=apiIntegratorKey

Fill in the ds-java-auth-final/privateKey.txt file with your private key from Quickstart_folder/src/main/resources/private.key

Right click on ds-java-auth-final folder and Open Folder as IntelliJ IDEA Project

In Project window, navigate to ds-java-auth-final/src/main/java/test.newOAuth/DsNewAuth

After building, right click and Run 'DsNewAuth.main()'

Please let me know if you have any questions